# last row is not merged in ms word table using aspose word for java

Tags: java, merge, ms-word, aspose.words

i have created a table in ms word by aspose.word using node. Now i need table in which 2nd column will be merged except first row
I got the merge column, but first and last row is not merging. First row is okay, because it was coded for that. But I cannot find out why last row is not merged.

> I have not enough reputation to attach image. So, I have to describe details of my output

**Here is my code**:

```
Document doc=new Document();


Table table = new Table(doc);
// Add the table to the document.

doc.getFirstSection().getBody().appendChild(table);//add table



Row row[]= new Row[4];Cell cell[] = new Cell[3];


for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {

row[i]=new Row(doc);table.appendChild(row[i]); 

 table.autoFit(AutoFitBehavior.AUTO_FIT_TO_WINDOW);//if I set this here last row not   //merge


       for (int j = 0; j < cell.length; j++) {

    cell[j]=new Cell(doc);
    row[i].appendChild(cell[j].deepClone(false));//cell creation
   // but in this position table.autoFit(AutoFitBehavior.AUTO_FIT_TO_WINDOW) create //no problem


    row[i].getLastCell().appendChild(new Paragraph(doc));


    if(row[i]==table.getFirstRow())
    {

    }

    else
    {
        if(j==1)
        {
            if(i==1)
            {
                row[i].getCells().get(j).getCellFormat().setVerticalMerge(CellMerge.FIRST); 

            }
            else
            {


                row[i].getCells().get(j).getCellFormat().setVerticalMerge(CellMerge.PREVIOUS);


            }   
        }

    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the following output by running your code. Kindly make sure that you are using the latest version of [Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/java/word-component.aspx). If you are having same issue with latest version too, please share your environment details so that I can reproduce it at my side.
[image: Output]
Download the latest version by visiting [Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/java/word-component.aspx) or directly download the [Jar file](http://maven.aspose.com/repository/repo/com/aspose/aspose-words/14.7.0/aspose-words-14.7.0-jdk16.jar) from our Maven repository.

Disclosure: I am a developer at Aspose.

Comment: Environment:
Eclipse Version:3.8 JDK:JavaSE 1.7 Aspose.Word:14.7.0 MS Word:2007
Operating System:Windows 7

Comment: I just have found the solution. it's all about the position of "table.autoFit(AutoFitBehavior.AUTO_FIT_TO_WINDOW)".
I set it after adding row. It is now fine after adding cell.

But now I have a question, what was the problem?

Comment: Please share your code including the autoFit() to diagnose the cause.